# How to execute public functions in PHP?

Tags: php

I've got a file connect.php.

```
public static function connect() {
    $file= file('data.txt');
        $hostname = rtrim($file[1]);
        $dbname   = rtrim($file[4]);
        $username = rtrim($file[7]);
        $password = rtrim($file[10]);
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host isailed, perhaps the service is down!');
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');
};
```

How can I access this function in other .php files?

```
connect();
```

doesn't work.

Comment: 1. Learn about variable scopes (you need to return it from the function). 2. Make sure you actually include the `connect.php` and if that function is part of an object, create it first. 3..  `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 (and **removed entirely** in PHP 7) and you should [stop using them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942) if you can. 
You should choose another API that allows you to use prepared statements (which you *really should*), like `mysqli_*` or PDO - see [choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Like others have said, you have to use include(), require() or similar to load code from files other than the one being executed. A common obstacle is to get the file path/include argument right. If you execute _echo ini_get('include_path')_ you will see which folder(s) PHP use as base folders when using relative paths. Absolute paths can also be used, of course.

Comment: If that is your entire connect.php, you are missing `<?php ... ?>` tags around your code.

Comment: @bytesized thanks... it works, thanks ;D fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it's not possible.  You have to access the code in order for it to work.  If you want THIS function available on another page then:

```
<?php include 'connect.php' ?>
```

With that, you can make your function call on that page and it will work.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: then the code is only printed on the site. And it is not working.
Error: Call to undefined function connect()

Comment: @12Hannibal12 considering that this says `public static`, I assume that this is part of a class. You would need to include the file with the class and then access the function like a static method such as `ClassName::connect();`. If the code is only printed on the site though, you likely need to add php tags to the class file as well.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn There is no class. the code above is the whole connect.php file.

Comment: @12Hannibal12 Then it doesn't need the `public static` modifiers. Those are only used for classes to make a function (or method for a class) able to be run from outside or inside the class. If there is no class, all functions are "public" and there is no such thing as static.

Comment: And @durbnpoisn, short tags? really?

Comment: Well, alright...  It is assumed that the page had been declared and this function was just being included.  But @JonathanKuhn is correct.  It should have a "php" after the first question mark. (edited)

Comment: so the code is function connect() {...} and in the .php just add the include path and it should work with executing connect(); ?
It does not work. Again, the code of the connect.php is printed on the site.

Comment: Oh - you mean it's just spitting out the plain text?  If that's the case, then your server is not executing the PHP.  That is a whole different matter.

Comment: Okay, it works. I forgot to set this into <?php .. ?> ;D

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the file, so your php file has access to the function. You can use [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) to do this.

`require('path/to/connect.php');`

Comment: Same as the other answer: the code is only printed on the site.